# set jquery context for all queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a site on a blank page so all of my jQuery calls resemble something like:

```
$('<div class="wtvr">Stuff</div>').appendTo(document.body);
$(':checkbox').map(function() { /* bunch of code */ });
```

And so on. It worked fine but here's my issue: I want to put that chunk of code into a div, on a page with other elements, the problem is the code that I'm using won't work if there are other elements on the page

I realize I can go through all of my code and rewrite it to work (ie `$(':checkbox')` to `$('#container :checkbox')`), My question is:

Can I somehow set up a context to base all my jQuery calls on? I want to make a div and run all of the code in the div's context.

I want to be able to do this:

```
$.context('#container');

//the following should do the same as $('#container').find(':checkbox').blah();
$(':checkbox').blah() // do like $('#container').find(':checkbox').blah();

//this should do the same as $('<div>Stuff</div>').appendTo('#container');
$('<div>Stuff</div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: I'd recommend just refactoring it to use $('#container').find(...) everywhere, etc... as you mentioned in your question. Even if it was possible to set a context (it's not unless you roll your own), you may not want to do that as it will interfere with other asynchronous jquery stuff happening outside of your module. (Interesting thought though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two statements. What I'll call "A" (`$(':checkbox').blah()`) and what I'll call "B" (`$('<div>Stuff</div>').appendTo(document.body);`).

Technically, yes you can rewrite "A" in this way:

```
$(':checkbox', $('#container')).blah();
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for an explanation. Better yet (and I'll explain why shortly) you could (should?) instead use:

```
var context = $('#container');
$(':checkbox', context).blah();
```

or

```
var context = $('#container');
context.find(':checkbox').blah();
```

For statement "B" however, you're telling jQuery *explicitly* to append that `<div>` to document.body - so no, there is no way to get `document.body` to mean `$('#container')`. And - just in case someone does have a crafty way to do so - it's not a good idea, because being counterintuitive, it will confuse every single person who ever reads the code (including you, two months from now when you come back to change something).

The much, **much** better method is to store your "context" in a temporary variable, like so:

```
var context = $('#container');
context.find(':checkbox').blah();
context.append('<div>Stuff</div>');
```

You'll see this pattern used all over the place. It's about the "least overhead" solution you'll find, by all important measures: typing the code, reading the code, code size, execution speed, cache utilization, and self-documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `context` feature in the current jQuery API.

- You can write a plugin if like to...
- Propose this new feature to jQuery, [this](http://forum.jquery.com/developing-jquery-core) is the place to ask it.

Comment: Yes there is - at least for OP's first statement (`$(':checkbox').blah()`), but not without an additional argument. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/.

Comment: @Chris. he didn't ask about that selector, He doesn't want to include "_additional argument_"

Answer (score 0):

No, and you shouldn't do that anyway.  It makes your code very confusing.

It's not much of an overhead to put the context in a variable:

```
var c = $('#container');

c.children(':checkbox').blash();
c.children('<div>Stuff</div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: I think you meant `c.(...)`, not `c.$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use curry to return a function that returns jQuery.

```
function makeContext( containerSelector ){
    var jContext = $(containerSelector);
    return function ( newQuery ){
        return jContext.find( newQuery );
    } 
}

var context = makeContext('#container');
context(':checkbox').blah();

//or if you prefer

$.context = makeContext('#container');
$.context(':checkbox').blah();
```

You could then set your context and do a find and replace for '$' in the relevant portion of code and replace with 'context'. If jQuery had a root context function, the question becomes, how do you escape the context when you need to?

Plus this way you can control, update and have multiple contexts like:

```
var homeContext  = makeContext('#homeElement');
var aboutContext = makeContext('#aboutElement');

//multiple context's living together
homeContext(':checkbox').blah();
aboutContext(':checkbox').foo();

//change context meaning later
homeContext = makeContext('home2Element');
homeContext(':checkbox').blah();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as you can get.

It works by creating a closure and re-defining $ as a wrapper that does what you mean.

Outside this closure jQuery will continue to operate normally so you don't break any scripts in the page that you're injecting your code into.

```
(function(){

    var fake_body = jQuery("#content"), $ = function(arg, context){
      return jQuery(arg,context? context : fake_body);
    };

    // your code here 
    $(':checkbox').blah(); 

    $('<div>Stuff</div>').appendTo(fake_body);
    // end your code

})();
```